# After I configured VPN my remote desktop session ended and won't reconnect

Tags: remote-desktop, vpn, windows-server-2008

Running server 2008 I connected via remote desktop and added the remote access role. After I configured it and pressed go, it said 'please wait' and then remote desktop disconnected. I'm not able to reconnect. When I try to VPN I get an error saying the policy isn't correct for the method I'm trying to use to VPN.

Any ideas what might have caused this? I now have to find a way to get back onto my remote server, and somehow undo whatever broke it.

Edit: Logged into our hosting account, apparently it won't ping either.

I can request a KVM session to fix it but I honestly don't know where to begin, so ideas on how I might undo it once I connect would be useful

Comment: any error code?

Comment: It simply won't connect. It won't ping, but VPN does produce the error about policy so it's still somehow listening.

Comment: Get into the KVM session. Check the Network Policy and Access Services role, specifically the Routing and RAS role service. I don't remember exactly what it is, but I remember not paying enough attention when setting up VPN and having a network interface misconfigured through there. You should always be able to disable the Routing and RAS service role to regain network connectivity.

Comment: Thanks, just waiting on them to enable the KVM session, I will try that.